# What is the path taken by an oxygen molecule as it passes into the lungs to a muscle cell in the body?

Tags: respiration, breathing, lungs

My teacher tried to describe this question to me, but I just don't  get it.

Comment: If you have anything specific to ask after looking at my answer below, please refine your question. Note that I voted to close because of the textbook-nature of the question and lack of research effort. See the [**help center on homework**](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) for assistance in asking good homework questions.

Answer (score 1):

See the figure below:

[image]

<sup>source: [Human Anatomy](http://humananatomybody.info/human-appendix-bone-2/)</sup>